# How to fill in VB form and send data to website fields

Tags: vb.net

i once saw a friend of mine whom was very good at visual basics and asp as well as c#. At the time i had no need to learn VB as i found php enough for my needs. While now since ive been in developing for a longer time i see why people use c#. It has its special place. My question relates to one of these special cases.

However i need your help to figure out how it was done.

What my friend did:
I had a wordpress site at the time. Because of our clients, we didnt want them to login backend and fill in the fields in the CMS. We wanted a deployed executable exe that the clients could install on pc and fill in the required data in simple forms that wont confuse them. Once the form was complete they would post the data to the wordpress cms in the background not visible to them. Using a webbrowser in the exe is what i recall my friend doing.

What i want to do:
I want clients to fill run an exe. They would then need to add login details to validate themselves. Once they logged in i want a very simple form that provides the necessary fields that the cms needs to fill in which will complete the post needed to render their page or profile on the actual website. In other words i want VB to connect to my website from a exe using forms to fill in data rather than going to the cms on a normal chrome or explorer browser.

I know you wondering why i want this. It seems like one hell of a work around. Well im a php developer whom needs a exe. I want to be able to package the exe physically in our portfolio when we hand it to clients. It becomes part of our presentation and welcome pack when joining out system.

This will help us when it comes to clients whom are not able to navigate a complex cms. If we make the cms to simple and old fashioned ( what clients generally are used to ) then we would have developed an outdated application in 2015 haha. Hence we want the best cms with modern features for the future, yet still need the old fashioned forms and simple structured date capturing clients are used to.

What you can help me with:
If i had a login, title and mobile number as the fields in my cms. The title had an ID named title and mobile number has an ID named Mobile. How can i do exactly what my friend did to login, and fill out forms then post the filled out form to my website cms that makes the post live. Please assist,:)

Kind regards

Comment: You can use [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) with the appropriately encoded name-value pairs (look up HTML form encoding) to make it look like you are a browser posting a form.

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution will be using a webbrowser control with visibility=hidden. Now Just change the value of some elements and invoke submit(). If you can't understand i will explain in details.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. Tanmay, I'm completely new to VB. Please could you provide details for me so I can follow, if it's not to much effort for u I would appreciate that a lot. If you wish I'm willing to link back to you for the great help. Even offering do follow links and guest post series if that would help any of your ventures or business model. 

Kind regards

Comment: But first i must tell you that my previous solution is only good for basic forms like login registration(with out any captcha) etc. But if you want to post , edit create wordpress you must follow Wordpress Api, like this example : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=419